# Change html page with jqm (1.4.0), passing parameter

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am building several apps and want to be able to reuse som code as separate HTML pages by passing parameters to them.

I would really like to pass parameters via ajax with one of these:
**Alt1**

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "../Photo/Photo.html", { reload: true, parameter: "dummyParameter"});
$.mobile.changePage("../Photo/Photo.html", { reloadPage: true, parameter: "dummyParameter"});
```

Problem is that the page wont **reload**.

If I use the below link the page is loaded/reloaded, but I cant seem to find the passed parameter.
**Alt2**

```
<a href="../Photo/Photo.html?paremeter=dummyParameter" data-ajax="false" data-role="button">Or through a basic link</a>
```

(I would prefeer to not generate the url in javascript as in alt2 but if what it takes...)

I use this code to try to retreive the parameters:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
    if (data.toPage[0].id == "Photo") {

        //var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];
        //var parameter = parameters.replace("paremeter=", "");


        var stuff = data.options.stuff;
        //showStuff("#p2", stuff);
    }
});
```

While I'm at it, if someone uses type script. Visual studio complains about that this call signature isnt correct:

```
  $(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data)
```

Expects one argument, the event, not the data. The plugin generates correct javascript but the IDE complains.

Thanks!

Comment: I went with using includefiles via "load".